# Unique id to restrict access to methods

Tags: java, uuid, access-modifiers

I have an object and I want to restrict access to some of its methods so that only the creator of the object can access them:

```
class RestrictedObject {

    private final UUID id;

    public RestrictedObject(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean restrictedMethod(UUID anId) {
        if (anId.equals(this.id)) {
            //do stuff
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The Object's creator would do this:

```
UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
RestrictedObject o = new RestrictedObject(id);
o.restrictedMethod(id);
```

Would this be good practice or a terrible idea?

Comment: A (possibly better) alternative would be to only share immutable views of the object. For instance, the creator would do `obj = new RestrictedObject()` and then, when sharing the restricted object, it would do `return new NonModifiableRestrictedObject(obj);` wher `NonModifiableRestrictedObject` is a wrapper that disallows all methods except the restricted method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to enforce access control in a system where your user can execute arbitrary Java code is a terrible idea.
It's basically the idea behind Java applets, it has been shown over and over again that it is very difficult to get right.
You need to make sure that the user with access to the object cant use tricks like reflection to read the UUID field.
I would question what problem you are actually trying to solve and find a better way of sandboxing the user.